# Login not working after changing firebase rules

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing a simple android app in which a user create account and then just login using google firebase. User is authenticated by sending OTP to their mobile number. Once user verify their mobile number by entering OTP, an account [image: default database] is created in the firebase. at
the same time some additional information (name, username, password, email etc) are saved in the realtime database [image: realtime database].

Sign code

```
final String userEnteredUsername = username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
final String userEnteredPassword = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userEnteredUsername);
checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            username.setError(null);
            username.setErrorEnabled(false);
           for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserHelperClass usersBean =                              
                user.getValue(UserHelperClass.class);
                String passwordFromDB = usersBean.password;
                if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) {
                    String nameFromDB = usersBean.name;
                    String usernameFromDB= usersBean.username;
                    String phoneNoFromDB= usersBean.phoneNo;
                    String emailFromDB= usersBean.email;

                    User localUser = new User(usernameFromDB, phoneNoFromDB);
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(localUser);
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("phoneNo", phoneNoFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Login.this.finish();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    password.setError("Wrong Password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
            }

        }else{
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            username.setError("No such User exist");
            username.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

sign up code

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(VerifyPhoneNo.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (  getIntent().getStringExtra("whatToDo").equalsIgnoreCase("updateData") ){
                          updateOldUserData();
                    }else {
                        UserHelperClass userHelperClass = new UserHelperClass(name, username, email, phoneNo, password);
                        reference.child(phoneNo).setValue(userHelperClass); 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneNo.this, AccountCreatedSuccessfullyMessageActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name").trim();
                        username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username").trim();
                        email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email").trim();
                        phoneNo = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNo").trim();
                        password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password").trim();

                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("username", username);
                        intent.putExtra("email", email);
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNo", phoneNo);
                        intent.putExtra("password", password);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneNo.this, task.getException().getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("error",  task.getException().getMessage().toString());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

To restrict unauthorized users I changed the rules as following

```
{ 
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now Login stopped working. Please help me where I am doing the mistake. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "Now Login stopped working"? If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: First I changed rules as ` {
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth !== null"
      
    }
  }
}`     It was working fine. But when I changed the rules as ` 
  {
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
`  It stopped working.

Comment: "DatabaseError: Permission denied"  gives this error

Comment: As you can see, the error message is straightforward, right?

Comment: `{ 
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}` Why its not working with these rules. although I have given permission to authenticated users to access their own data

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated? How do you check that? Please provide an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229154/discussion-between-ibrahim-and-alex-mamo).